# Recursion -finding the smallest number

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am lerning recursion and would like to know whats wrong with my solution. I am trying to find the smallest numbers using recursion(I know using a loop etc is much easier, but as I am learning recursion, I try to write a recursive function for that). Thanks!

```
function min(arr) {

  if (arr.length==1){
    return arr[0];
  }
  else if(arr[0]>arr[1]) {

    return min(arr.slice(1));   
  }
  else {
    min(arr[0]+ arr.slice(2)); 
  }
}
min([-5,4,0,8,5]);
```

Comment: You forgot the `return` before the last recursive call.

Comment: *"I [...] would like to know whats wrong with my solution"* Why do you think something is wrong? What is the output you get and what do you expect? Or do you get an error? What do you think `arr[0]+ arr.slice(2)` is doing?

Comment: I expect to get the smallest number and Im getting "," and I put arr[0]+ arr.slice(2) because the min fun should be called again with an array but exclude arr[1] in case that arr[0]<arr[1]

Comment: Walk through your code with a debugger.

Comment: I didn't understand your solution at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `concat` to join the arrays and not `+`. Try this:

```
function min(arr) {
  if (arr.length==1){
    return arr[0];
  }
  else if(arr[0]>arr[1]) {
    return min(arr.slice(1));   
  }
  else {
    return min([arr[0]].concat(arr.slice(2))); 
  }
}
```

Here's a documentation link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: thank you! It works. Using + was wrong because it is an array, not a string or the value stored in a variable I am adding, correct?

Comment: Yes. Interestingly, Javascript didn't complain to you that you actually turning the array into a string (by using the + operator) and it still returned the string back into the min function and tried to complete the function!

Answer (score 2):

The classic form of recursion applied to this problem would be:

```
function min(a) {
  function smaller(a, b) { return a < b ? a : b; }

  return a.length ? smaller(min(a.slice(1)), a[0]) : Infinity;
}
```

In ES6:

```
function min([head, ...tail]) {
  function smaller(a, b) { return a < b ? a : b; }

  return head === undefined ? Infinity : smaller(head, min(tail));
}
```

Here is an alternative approach, which passes the current minimum down to each recursive iteration. This has the advantage that it can be tail-optimized. Babel succeeds at doing that.

```
function min([head, ...tail], cur = Infinity) {
  return head === undefined ? cur : min(tail, head < cur ? head : cur);
}
```

Comment: The ES6 version is a very nice example of destructuring and an easy to read implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function recursiveMinNumber(items){ 

       if(items.length === 1){
         return items[0] //Base-case reached
          }
      else{
            if(items[0]<=items[items.length-1]){
                items.pop() //remove the last item in the array
                return recursiveMinNumber(items) 
            }
            else{
                return recursiveMinNumber(items.slice(1)) //remove the first item in the array
            }
         }
    }
    
    console.log(recursiveMinNumber([2,22,3,3,4,44,33]))
```